# Trying to serve files that are in a byte array to my details view in an ASP.NET Core 2 MVC web app

Tags: asp.net, arrays, database, file, model-view-controller

Currently I have a database with two tables, one table is for products and the other is for file attachments for these products. hen I edit my product, I have an upload form to attach a file. It is uploading to the database fine.

What I need help with is how to serve those files back to the details view of the product as links so they can download them.

Here is my model for the file attachment.

```
namespace Product.Models
{
    public class FileAttachments
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public byte[] Attachments { get; set; }
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`ProductID` is my key for my main table

Here is my upload method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upload(ICollection<IFormFile> files, int ID)
{
        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            FileAttachments NewFile = new FileAttachments();
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            f.CopyTo(ms);

            NewFile.Attachments = ms.ToArray();
            NewFile.ProductID = ID;
            NewFile.FileName = f.FileName;
            NewFile.MimeType = f.ContentType;

            _db.Attach(NewFile);
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return Redirect(Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I figured out how to do it...

This gets the files in my attachment controller.

```
        public FileContentResult GetFile(int id)
        {
            FileAttachments attachment = _db.FileAttachments.Find(id);
            if (attachment.Attachments != null)
                return File(attachment.Attachments, attachment.MimeType, attachment.FileName);
            else
                return null;
        }
```

This is the code I put in my details view

```
            <table class="table table-striped" id="AttachmentTable">
                @foreach (FileAttachments attachment in Model.FileAttachments)
                {
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink(attachment.FileName, "GetFile", "Attachment", new { Id = attachment.ID }, null)
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Attachment", new { id = attachment.ID, returnUrl = Context.Request.Path }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" })
                </td>
                }
            </table>
```